# Можно ли как-то узнать, что пользователь искал недавно в поисковиках?

Tags: поисковые-системы, реклама

Здравствуйте, уважаемые программисты!

У меня есть такой вопрос: можно ли как-то узнать, что пользователь искал недавно в поисковиках (Google, Яндекс и др.), для вывода актуальной рекламы на своем сайте?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно:

```
 ...
 window.getSurfHistory();
 ...
```

Ну, а если честно, на первый взгляд вопрос может показаться нелепым, т.к. если б это было возможно, то какой тогда был бы смысл от обеспечения пользователю приватности и анонимности в сети? Не нужно было бы собирать о нем информацию из различных форм ввода, а достаточно было бы просто заглянуть в его историю поиска и узнать о нем много чего интересного и нужного. Так что нет, нельзя вот так просто взять и узнать о пользователях то, что обычно находится в его личной зоне.

Но зато можно проделать это сложно, как это, например, делает механизм множественных рекламных баннеров от одной компании, установленных на разных сайтах в сети. Баннеры сохраняют за собою полное право отправлять на сервер любую информацию(в т.ч. и Cookies определенного сайта). Таким образом, если, допустим, баннер определенной рекламной компании стоит на сайтах A, B и C, и пользователь совершил, к примеру, такую схему серфинга: A->C->B->A, то этот пользователь потеряет свою анонимность и даст той самой компании точно знать, что он был на сайте A, затем перешел на сайт C, оттуда на B, а затем снова вернулся на A.

Правда, вот сложность заключается в том, чтобы заставить владельца сайта вставить код рекламного баннера на свой сайт.

Comment: @0xFFh, спасибо за ответ! Просто я недавно в Яндексе искал некоторую информацию, после перешел на сайт ВКонтакте и там в рекламе увидел информацию, которую я искал!

Comment: @cas-live, это уже другой механизм, предоставляемый специально поисковыми системами рекламным компаниям для отображения только той информации, которая носит рекламный характер. К примеру, если вы будете искать в поисковиках XXX контент, с наибольшей долей вероятности в соцсетях его вы не увидите. Хотя, если же искать товары, связанные с XXX, то вполне вероятно, что в скором времени они будут "светиться" во всех социальных сервисах, где только имеется аккаунт.

Comment: @0xFFh, спасибо за ответ, вопрос закрыт

Comment: @cas-live: С практической стороны, пользуйтесь Adblock Plus. Отключив рекламу, вы заодно и не будете попадать в списки предпочтений баннерных сетей.

Comment: @AseN хотите - смейтесь, хотите - нет, но однажды произошел такой случай. Сидя за ПК вблизи к микрофону разговаривал с кем-то об очень, так скажем, плачевном состоянии здоровья одного из своих родственников. Спустя пару часов Google предложил мне рекламу похоронного бюро. Такие дела. И как тут параноиком не стать...

Comment: Полагаю, такая наивность излишня - едва ли гуглу есть дело до глубинного копания в пролетарских делах - поверхностно, еще ладно :)